# Where Clause doesnt NOT returning the correct data in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Let's say I have Eloquent Query in

```
$drivers = Driver::whereRaw('driver_number not in (select driver_number from buses) OR driver_number = ?', [$bus->driver_number])
                    ->where('station_id', 3)
                    ->get();
```

So i want to get all drivers that assigned to a bus with station 3 but it returning all drivers, **I just want drivers in Station 3**, but it seems this is not working.

here is the Driver Table

[image]

Comment: why you are using this:- `whereRaw('driver_number not in (select driver_number from buses) OR driver_number = ?', [$bus->driver_number])`

Comment: because it return the data i want, but how should i specify the staion @SahilGupta

Comment: I didn't understand your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve all the driver number from the Bus

```
$driverNumbers = Bus::pluck('driver_number');
```

This will retrieve all the drivers based on the condition you mention above.

```
$drivers = Driver::where('station_id', 3)
                 ->whereNotIn('driver_number', $driverNumbers)
                 ->where('driver_number', '<>', $bus->driver_number)
                 ->get();
```

Comment: the last one wont work, it displays nothing, but the above elquent is working, but i need only station 3 drivers for data returned by that eloquent query.

Comment: What do you get when you only query `Driver::where('station_id',3)`? Is it displaying all the drivers with **station_id 3**? If yes, then `DB::raw` is having a problem.